# Why $\frac{dx}{|x|}$ is a Haar measure on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: measure-theory, haar-measure

This is in "A course in the abstract harmonic analysis by G.B. Follan on page 45"

> Why $\frac{dx}{|x|}$ is a Haar measure on multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

I've started as following

$\frac{dax}{|ax|}=\frac{adx}{|ax|}$

but I couldn't figure out the result

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: be careful, we using a change of variables the multiplicative factor you obtain is not the determinant of the jacobian (in this case $a$) but its absolute value (in this case $|a|$). In others words $d(ax)=|a| dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{aE} \frac 1 {|x|} \, dx =\int_{E} \frac 1 {|x|} \, dx$ for all Borel sets $E$ in $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ and all $a \neq 0$ (by an obvious change of variable). This is the definition of Haar measure.

Comment: @Dear Kavi Rama Murthy, I have a problem with $\frac{1}{|x|}$

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: $\frac{ads}{|a||x|}=\frac{ds}{|x|}$

Comment: You can understand what is happening by taking a special case. Take $E=(1,2)$ and $a=-1$. See what $\int_{aE} \frac 1 {|x|} \, dx$ is.